# swift auth with post in body

Tags: swift, authentication, post

Please help me with my problem. I try to auth in web site with swift.For test i try auth with postman - username and password in body - all ok, a have finish auth.

Postman screenShot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL3yp.png

when i try to auth with my code, in webview i did not auth. i see cookie, and it have not auth cookie. Where is my mistake? this is my auth code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            ViewController.auth(outError: {outError in
                if outError != nil {
                    print("error")
                }
                else {
                    print("not nil")
                }
            }, responseStringOut: {responseStringOut in

                print("all ok")

            })

        let url = NSURL (string: "https://XXXXXXXX.XX")
        var requestObj = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
    }

    class func auth(outError: @escaping (String)->Void, responseStringOut: @escaping (String)->Void)  {
        print("AUTH START!")
        //, responseStringOut: @escaping (String)->Void
        let url = URL(string: "https://XXXXX.XX")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let postString = "username=XXX&password=XXX"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        //print(postString)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            print("RESPONSE:")
            print(response)
            setMyCookie()

        }

        task.resume()
    }

    class func setMyCookie() {
        if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
            for cookie in cookies {
                NSLog("cookie: \(cookie)")
            }
        }

}

}
```

Comment: `webView.loadRequest(requestObj)` is called BEFORE `setMyCookie` is called.  Also you don't seem to call your closure in `auth()`, so it's it's strange.

Comment: I make test - make button, and  make action after push it: Set Cookie and open Url. I push it after 10 sec program start (at this time i think must be auth if all good), but i get the same result. May be i have error with post request?